# Auto retrieve image from Download folder and show in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a Download folder in which there are many images. I want to get a single image  from that folder and show into ImageView. Code is given below I am using this code to **onCreate()** method. So that there is no need to choose from the folder. I have already given required permission. But getting  java.io.FileNotFoundException: Multiple items at content://media/external/images/media at given code.

image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedimg);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

```
    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
    String[] filePaths = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePaths, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePaths[0]);
    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+picturePath );
    c.close();
    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    try {


        Uri selectedimg = intent.getData();
        image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedimg);
        Bitmap resizedBmp = Helpers.resizeForPreview(image);
        selectImage.setImageBitmap(resizedBmp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("path of image ", picturePath + " "+ Uri.parse(picturePath));

    selectImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Comment: Do you have the path to the Image?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 Yeah I have given path as well but did not got any help

Comment: I have posted an answer please check and let me know if that works for you or not.

Comment: Glad, You solved it. It would be better if you could post the answer and mark your answer as correct so that others could also get benefited from it.